# How to force desktop browser to open in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, html, viewport

Is there a way that i can force google chrome on my pc to open my web project in a mobile view port automatically

I thought changing the meta tag of the view port in my DOM would get the job done.

Comment: Thank god that is not possible.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried?

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to take a look of your project in mobile view, you would simply just use the DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and then click the Toggle device Toolbar (Top left Conner icon) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to mobile view.